# Setting up a project for release in visual studio 2013

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio

I'm working on a C# project that is nearing release. As part of this, I have started building the project and testing it on another machine. This has revealed some odd problems. My biggest concern, though, is that my project is failing to run. I can do some basic things, but when I try to use my projects primary functionality it crashes. Using Visual Studio, I was able to determine the exception that was causing the crash.

Essentially, I'm getting a FileNotFoundException on the dll that contains most of my project's functional code. I'm not sure if I've made an error in adding the dll to my project, or if there's a problem in one of the files in the dll.

The dll was added as a reference using the **Project** -> **Add Reerences** feature of the user interface.

The dll contains three files which contain absolute file paths (these are for #import statements). Example follows.

```
#import "C:\Users\Me\Documents\Projects\MyProject\Delegates\bin\MyDelegate.tlb" raw_interfaces_only
```

My hang up is I'm not exactly sure what I'm doing wrong here. I suspect that those import statements are causing problems, but I'm not exactly sure how to fix them if they in fact are the problem. This is my first c#/c++ project so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the dll as a reference DOES NOT include the dll with your project--you are simply telling your project to use the library for your code.  The dll will need to be installed on all computers that run your application, for your application to use the dll.

If the dll also uses three files (as you specified), then those files must also be included, and be installed in the expected path.

Presuming you have redistribution rights on the dll you mention, you can include the dll in your project.  Be sure to set the "copy" property as "copy always" or "copy if newer" and change the reference to use the copy that ends up in you bin folder.   Then you only need to be sure to include that dll and install it in the same folder as your application.